# Android parcelable - write nullable long

Tags: android, kotlin, nullable, parcelable, type-mismatch

I have my parcelable class Article:

```
class Article : Parcelable {

    var image: Long? = null
    var category: String? = null
    var videos: String? = null

    constructor(data: JSONObject) {
        if (condition) image = 50000L
        category = data.getString("category")
        videos = data.getString("videos")
    }

    private constructor(parcel: Parcel) {
        image = parcel.readLong()
        category = parcel.readString()
        videos = parcel.readString()
    }

    override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        dest.writeLong(image) // error here
        dest.writeString(category)
        dest.writeString(videos)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int = 0

    companion object {
        @JvmField val CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator<Article> = object : Parcelable.Creator<Article> {
            override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): Article = Article(parcel)
            override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Article?> = arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

But my class is getting a type mismatch at writing the image var. It is expecting a Long and not a Long?. I do understand that this could be solved if I do something like this:

```
dest.writeLong(image!!)
```

But the problem is that this var could really be null on my context.
I don't want either to define my image var as a default value like 0. I really want the var to remain nullable.

Is there any way to write a nullable var?

Comment: You can simply put it like this

image?.let{dest.writeLong(it)}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your image variable should keep nullable

`parcel.readValue(Long::class.java.classLoader) as? Long`

`parcel.writeValue(image)`

Answer (score 3):

I use extension functions to solve problems like these in my projects now:

```
private const val NULL_ELEMENT_FLAG = 0;
private const val NONNULL_ELEMENT_FLAG = 1;

Parcel.writeNullableLong(l: Long?) {
    if (l != null) {
        writeInt(NONNULL_ELEMENT_FLAG);
        writeLong(l);
    } else {
        writeInt(NULL_ELEMENT_FLAG);
    }
}

Parcel.readNullableLong(): Long? =
    when (readInt()) {
        NONNULL_ELEMENT_FLAG -> readLong()
        else -> null
    }
```

---

In Java, the way I handle `Long` (as opposed to `long`) is patterned after the Android source code for writing other "nullable" types: you first write some sort of marker value to indicate null vs non-null, and then you conditionally write the real value.

```
private static final int NULL_ELEMENT_FLAG = 0;
private static final int NONNULL_ELEMENT_FLAG = 1;

public static void writeLong(Parcel dest, Long l) {
    if (l != null) {
        dest.writeInt(NONNULL_ELEMENT_FLAG);
        dest.writeLong(l);
    }
    else {
        dest.writeInt(NULL_ELEMENT_FLAG);
    }
}

public static Long readLong(Parcel in) {
    if (in.readInt() != NULL_ELEMENT_FLAG) {
        return in.readLong();
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Hopefully you can adapt this to kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin you have to handle null cases for *primitive types* of Kotlin which are *objects* in Java (`Long` as opposed to `long`). You can apply the following logic to any such type.

```
private fun writeNullableLongToParcel(l: Long?): Long = when(l) {
      null -> -1
      else -> l
}
```

For `Boolean`, you do something like this:

```
private fun writeBooleanToParcel(bool: Boolean?): Int = when(bool) {
      true -> 1
      false -> 0
      else -> -1
}
```

Add these to your `Parcelable` data class and use them in `writeToParcel`

```
parcel?.writeLong(writeNullableLongToParcel(myLong))
```

Comment: What about the case of actually `myLong = -1`? This solution simply ignores that fact.

Comment: @musooff If `myLong = -1` that comes under the `else` part of the `when`. I think tha'ts pretty clear.

Comment: Well, I get that. The problem is you are equating null case to -1. Both null cases and -1 will be converted to -1. So, while reading you loose information wether the value was -1 or null in the first place.

Comment: @musooff It could be further changed to check additional cases if needed such as if `myLong < 0`.
`l == null -> -1`
`l < 0 -> -1` 
`else -> l`
I think this is inferred by the reader.

Comment: @musooff well, the code of the answer is on the right track, but didn't managed it for a generic numberic value. Here the answer for you: `value == null -> 0`, `value < 0 -> value`, `else -> value + 1`, and vice versa. https://pl.kotl.in/-quwTsdZE

Answer (score 0):

Write value if not null otherwise a default value

`longValue?.let { parcel.writeLong(it) }?:let{ parcel.writeLong(DEFAULT_VALUE)}`